# Is using CAPS LOCK instead of mark-down formatting rude or abusive

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags, rude-or-abusive, unfriendly-or-unkind

Yesterday, I came across a post that was about a Python package installation. I was commenting to see if they could give more info, when I noticed the user was using too much caps lock on their posts. I calmly warned them and then edited the question later. The user kept on using caps.

I wanted to know if this post's comments should be flagged because I don't want to make any harsh moves.

The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730668/pip-install-backtest-python) [deleted so only visible to 10k users; some comments deleted].

Comment: worst case scenario... the flag gets declined, and hopefully you learn from it. */shrug*

Comment: i don't think capitalization alone is enough to push something from being fine to being unkind/unwelcoming/rude/abusive.

Comment: Regarding downvotes on _this_ question: it's a good thing that the OP asked here instead of just flagging incorrectly... we should not discourage asking meta for advice.

Comment: "*I calmly warned them and then edited the question later. The user kept on using caps.*" I don't see that in the question. What happened to your comment?

Comment: It went away...

Comment: @TrooperZ possibly automatically, due to the meta attention and multiple flags.

Comment: Surprisingly related: [Posted at almost the same time as the original CAPS LOCK post to the Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/69126/40023)

Comment: @DavyM What a coincidence!

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank: the question is deleted so only visible to 10k users; but even for those of us who can see it, some comments (such as NicolBolas') were deleted. If the comment deletion is the side-effect of flagging for potential 'unfriendly', then that will be destructive.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's a very clear case of someone simply not knowing how to format their text properly (thinking that ALL CAPS is a suitable form of emphasis, rather than using italics), not someone trying to be rude or insulting to people.  Feel free to fix it, along with the various other presentation errors with the post.

If there's some evidence that the user is doing it to be disruptive, and that they are doing so *intentionally*, then there's some context that's missing.  If that's the case, certainly don't flag the post as "rude" (the moderator wouldn't see such context and would likely decline the flag, because using caps isn't abusive), use a custom flag to explain why you feel the user is using improper formatting intentionally.

Comment: But what about the comments?

Comment: @TrooperZ What about them?

Comment: What should we do?

Comment: @TrooperZ Nothing.  Unless you see some other problem than just how they're formatted.

Comment: @TrooperZ: Have you considered... asking them to stop using ALL CAPS like that?

Comment: Some people are unaccustomed to being able to format in some environments. For example, I get emails that enforce "plain text". And years ago, there was no formatting in "forums" and similar venues. Then it can make sense to use Caps for emphasis and I do it, myself, when having to answer plain text email. It's a question of *how much*, really... What I can see in that now-deleted post is in no way rude or over-bearing <shrug>

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Agreed, that was even the norm on dial-up BBS's before internet was commonplace.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Those mechanisms are very localized. ALL CAPS for a word or two has long been used, and in my experience (even in the dial-up BBS days) is that all caps is much more prevalent for emphasis, but can become bothersome if over used.

Comment: Didn't see the comment, but I am not disputing that.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank The author may not even have been alive for decades, so it's not necessarily fair to expect them to automatically know this. Although to my eyes it does seem kind of obvious...

Answer (score 18):

Let's not feel like we're walking on egg shells here.  Take a moment to calmly look at the post and see what's really being said.

The user is using caps for emphasis, which isn't exactly desirable, but is definitely not ***rude***.  While all-caps translates to shouting, it doesn't seem to be the case that this is the OP's intent.

I don't see much value in the way of *us* going in and trying to calm them down, either.  Comments like that have a tendency to escalate and get out of control quickly, so I'd personally like to steer clear.

**Should the behavior persist** yet not rise to the occasion of impoliteness or rudeness, a simple custom mod flag explaining what's going on and asking the mod to see if they can use a different way to show emphasis would be enough.

This doesn't require a deep and analytical Meta post when this happens.  If you don't know what to do, it's better to **do nothing** and let another person deal with it.

Comment: Using all capitals is shouting, shouting is rude (unless you are on fire or I'm about to get killed by something, eg a car speeding my way)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel then you could flag it (because you "know" it is rude. I like Makoto's point that flagging here should be kinda like the review queue: "If *you* are *not sure* then there is no action needed". I personally would not have considered it rude because I occasionally work with people who type in all caps due to various reasons (like ELL who hit cap-lock on accident and because it is in a weird place when compared to their native keyboard, and only marked in English, they cannot re-find it until I see and show them).

Comment: On the subject of the previous comment, one of my Japanese students pointed me to [this question on the Japanese Language SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15780/how-would-one-emulate-capitalized-letters-in-japanese) when I asked them, today, why the ALL CAPS IS SHOUTING was confusing after they "shouted" at me in a message.

Answer (score 11):

**No, wrong capitalization does not make a post rude any more than excessive bold font does**.

The question might have other problems though; I would consider voting to close.

Comment: I had a debate or was it I just listened to a rant... yes that was it I listened to a rant against me for using  !    Why am I shouting !! Stop it!

Comment: Using all capitals is shouting, shouting is rude. Using all bold sentences is raising your voice, almost shouting, which is borderline rude.

Comment: I AGREE WITH THE SENTIMENT EXPRESSED IN THE FIRST PARAGRAPH. @MarkRotteveel, I think what you're saying holds true in arguments, but not when somebody is just emphasising things in a post where none of the content is adversarial. In that context it's merely annoying, rather than rude.

Answer (score 1):

The user's behavior seems to be inappropriate, but I don't think flagging is the right first step response.

The first step probably should be letting them know that ALL CAPS is considered shouting, which is inappropriate and unnecessary. The user's comments seem to suggest that they're genuinely frustrated with the circumstances, so letting them know that they're acting out could help them calm down.

If they ignore your suggestion or otherwise continue to act inappropriately, I would say that the time has come to escalate things to the level of flagging. I wouldn't go so far as "Harassment, Bigotry, or Abuse", just "Unwelcoming/Unkind". Though a "something else" flag might help the moderator better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the person understood how to write normally and HOW TO USE CAPS. As evidenced by their question, and all the comments. Especially telling is this:

Comment to the OP:

> stop using caps.

OP's reply:

> CAPS? what´s caps?

Pretty much any flag would be valid, as the comments were so persistent and it gave the appearance that the OP was frustrated and shouting at people. Whether or not that was the truth behind it, we cannot be sure. We can only go by what the usual internet user would regard as shouting in text and that the OP clearly understood what caps are, and made a joke of it.

---

[image]

Reasoning of marking flags as helpful:

Yeh skirts into abuse.
Not friendly.
No longer needed.
Custom flag "hey this person keeps using CAPS, can you have a look?".

---

As for flag preference, if in doubt go for the lower flag. Not sure it's abusive, flag unfriendly. *Or* raise a custom mod flag.

Comment: As I see it the problem is that persistence in CAPS usage only skirts the edge of rudeness.  Certainly the poster's now-deleted reply to the request to stop and their subsequent perseverence appear to be calculated to irritate, but is policing this level of unfriendliness really something that the mods want to be doing?

Comment: @JohnBollinger to be honest, I'm tired of the whole thing. What is being flagged is between both extremes of flag worthy and not. People complain on meta if we delete a comment, or decline a flag. To get hauled over the coals if we do or if we don't. I'm sick of it. Why can't people see that from the mod point of view. We're juggling sharp pieces of glass and are blamed when we drop them. It's actually impossible. All I'm saying is, flag it and they would be deleted. Do I think they're rude? Not alone, it's the sheer number of them with the sarcastic remark at the end I find rude.

Comment: You and the other mods have my sympathy, @Yvette, and your sentiment is exactly the kind of thing I suspected.  I, for one, appreciate the job you all do.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank you it's appreciated and I'll let the other mods know. I think people get worked up and there's been a lot of research into the nature of group mentality. It changes the individual at times and people can react as one larger entity. That's something that we come to recognise with age and maturity (being half a century). For all my attempting to reach people. I understand them a lot more than they realise. I have 3 children the same age as many people on here. For a lot of people they need a decade or two and that will help :D BUT they have the energy the older ones don't.

Comment: I for one appreciate that entitled askers get the same treatment as answerers in terms of scrutiny of niceness in their comments.

Comment: @AndrasDeak exactly. There's so much focus on welcoming, there needs to be focus on 'arriving'.